# Referencing pawn player in c++ ue4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

for a project i am designing a tank game and want a tank to be constantly looking at my player but after looking online a lot i haven't found a solution to referencing my player in c++

```
 ATank* myCharacter = Cast<ATank>(this);

     if (myCharacter)
     {
         FVector targetLocation = myCharacter->GetActorLocation();
         FVector myLocation = GetActorLocation();

         FRotator newrot = (myLocation -targetLocation).Rotation();

         NewRotation.Yaw = newrot.Yaw;
         SetActorRotation(NewRotation);
     }
```

above is what i have at the moment which does nothing as its not finding the player and before i put the if statement in it was just crashing, any help/guidance is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with UE4, but that sounds as though `Cast<ATank>(this)` yields `nullptr`. Hence, you'll probably need to give more code to allow people who are more familiar with UE4 (if the problem indeed lies there) to see what class `this`. I take it `Cast` is some kind of cast-function of UE4.

Comment: Your code does not make any sense - what is `this`? You treat it as both the tank and the player character at the same time? In which class does this code live?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerPawn(...)` [UE Docs](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Kismet/UGameplayStatics/GetPlayerPawn/index.html) and each `ATank` can hold it's reference to your pawn. Then you should check if your stored reference is not null and IsValidLowLevel(). Next step is to perform desired computations using player pawn reference.

Comment: GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPawn() is also usable.